# Text speech software for flash presentation

Tags: audio-recording, microphone

Hello Everyone,

I have made so many Flash presentations, but every time i stuck on one part. I need to get a professional vocal audio added to my presentation. So that when a slide is running its explanation can be done vocally.

I have seen this on a website [Umbraco](http://umbraco.com/), here in the flash presentation on the very first page, someone is speaking about the content (This voice i have heard so many times on different presentations),

**My Question is:- Is that a computer generated voice or a software made voice or just someone speaking himself and recorded.**

If it is from a software can somebody help me to find it out, please :) Thanks in advance

I also tested this one :- http://www.naturalreaders.com/index.htm but this also not looks so professional

Comment: It definitely sounds like a real person to me.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a voice actor not a computer generated voice.

Have you considered looking on a site like [Freelancer](http://www.freelancer.co.uk/directory/freelancer.php) to attempt to hire someone to provide the voice over for your presentation?